# Node.js process.stdout.write is flickering in a for loop

Tags: node.js, console

I am making a console interface, and using a for loop.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
  process.stdout.clearLine();
  process.stdout.cursorTo(0);
  process.stdout.write('Something: ' + i);
}
```

when I use this, the `'Something: i'` flickers. Is there any way to make it not flicker?

EDIT:
I am using the windows command prompt, is there a way to prevent the flickering there?

Comment: Not in a cross-terminal way, although “flickering” is a bit nebulous. In the olden days we’d just backspace over what we wanted to change (remember spinning cursors at 300 baud? No? Anyone?). Clearing the entire line is more likely to cause a flash, and it probably depends on the emulator’s implementation.

Comment: I am using the windows command line, is there any way not to cause a flash on there?

Comment: What an underrated question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were sooo close! 
So the flicker is happening because you are clearing the **whole line**, You need to just clear the stream(in your case STDOUT) from **right side of your cursor**.

According to the [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/tty.html#tty_writestream_clearline_dir_callback):

```
process.stdout.clearLine(1);
```

This will do the trick.

Full code from your example:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
  process.stdout.clearLine(1);// <<--here
  process.stdout.cursorTo(0);
  process.stdout.write('Something: ' + i);
}
```